# How to add two bytes together in Java, with wrap around if there is overflow

Tags: java, checksum, binary-data, addition

I need to add up all of the bytes in a byte array consisting of only ASCII characters using one's complement binary addition, storing the result as a single byte checksum.

I am trying to start with the basics by figuring out how to add just 2 bytes together, but have no idea how to "wrap around" if there is an extra bit when adding the two binary values.

I have made a tester program so I can play around with different values. In the below example I am trying to add two  binary numbers, each representing the decimal value 255.

```
byte b1 = (byte) 255;
String s1 = String.format("%8s",Integer.toBinaryString(b1 & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0');
System.out.println("byte 1: " + s1); // 1111111

byte b2 = (byte) 255;
String s2 = String.format("%8s",Integer.toBinaryString(b2 & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0');
System.out.println("byte 2: " + s2); // 1111111

byte sum = 0;

sum += b1;
sum += b2;

String s3 = String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(sum & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0');
System.out.println("sum of byte 1 and byte 2: " + s3); // should be 1111111
```

I expected the output to be:

byte 1: 11111111
byte 2: 11111111
sum of byte 1 and byte 2: 11111111

but the actual output is:

byte 1: 11111111
byte 2: 11111111
sum of byte 1 and byte 2: 11111110

How do I wrap around the extra bit so that I get the correct result?

Comment: If you set `b1` to `254`, what result do you expect?

Comment: I'd expect the sum (11111110 + 11111111) to be 11111110 but instead get 11111101 because the extra bit is not being wrapped around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're only working with `byte`, you can store the result of your addition in a larger primitive type, such as an `int`. By doing this, you'll have easy access to the *overflow bit*, which you can extract (using bitwise operations) and add to the existing sum:

```
int sum = b1 + b2;
sum += (sum >> 8) & 1;
String s3 = String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(sum & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0');
System.out.println("sum of byte 1 and byte 2: " + s3); // should be 11111111
```

If the value of the *overflow bit* is `0`, then nothing happens. But if it's `1`, overflow occurred and the bit will wrap around.

Comment: Thank you! Now I'll be able to put together an algorithm to calculate a checksum of a byte array. And thanks for correcting my terminology of the overflow bit!